# Latitude and longitude addresses for Google Maps always show Chinese locations

Tags: android, google-maps

## The Problem

I'm trying to retrieve latitude and longitude from an address using [Geocoder.getFromLocationName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

> It works perfectly for some Android devices, but it **keeps showing Chinese latitude and longitude addresses for my Xiamoi mobile phone**. However, it should be showing my location - **Saket, Delhi, India**.

Here's the code:

```
public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {    
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> address;
    LatLng p1 = null;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        if (address == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();
        p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        return p1;
    }
}
```

Comment: share the address and your sample code

Comment: please check my code i have shared

Comment: Hi Sushil, please see my answer in response to the code you have added.

Comment: resolved issue by using  `getFromLocationName(String locationName, int maxResults, double lowerLeftLatitude, double lowerLeftLongitude, double upperRightLatitude, double upperRightLongitude)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Change the Locale

The Locale passed into the [Geocoder constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#Geocoder%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.Locale%29) represents the **desired [Locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) for the query results**. This applies the the following code:

```
 Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
```

## Be wary of the default locale

From the documentation for [Locale.getDefault();](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault%28%29)

> Note that there are many convenience methods that automatically use the default locale, but using them may lead to subtle bugs.
>
> A common mistake is to implicitly use the default locale when producing output meant to be machine-readable. This tends to work on the developer's test devices (especially because so many developers use en_US), but fails when run on a device whose user is in a more complex locale.

The default Locale is most likely [China](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#CHINA). This makes sense seeing as [Xiaomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaomi) is a Chinese manufacturer. This is probably why you keep getting Chinese addresses.

## Test

Try the following and check your logs to see what the locale is being set to:

```
Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
Log.i("MyActivity", defaultLocale.toString());
```